# Need to add column from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models: `Account` and `Profile`. In `Account` I have `role` column. I need to add `role` column to `profiles` table.

I include in `Profile` `has_one :account` association and `belongs_to :profile` in `Account` model. I think the solution is near that.

#### profile.rb

```rb
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  
  has_one :account
end
```

#### acount.rb

```rb
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  devise :registerable, :database_authenticatable, :rememberable,
         :trackable, :confirmable, :lockable, :recoverable, :validatable

  belongs_to :profile, foreign_key: 'profile_id'
  enum role: %i[user admin]
end
```

#### schema.rb

```rb
  create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.string "remember_token"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string "unconfirmed_email"
    t.integer "failed_attempts", default: 0, null: false
    t.string "unlock_token"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "profile_id", null: false
    t.integer "role", default: 0
    t.index ["profile_id"], name: "index_accounts_on_profile_id"
  end

  create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "last_name", null: false
    t.string "first_name", null: false
    t.string "middle_name"
    t.string "email", null: false
    t.text "about"
    t.date "hire_date", null: false
  end
```

I want to which is in `profiles` table to be added in column `Account.role`.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Do you want to be able to access the value in the `role` column from an instance of `Profile`, or do you want to create a new column in `profiles` and duplicate the value from `accounts`?

Comment: @StefanRendevski second. I want create new column in ```profiles``` and include there ```role``` column value from ```accounts``` table.

Comment: Can you explain why do you want to do that? You shouldn't have duplicate data in your relational database, that's just wrong. Unless you plan on deleting the original data, there's no need to copy it as you'll always be able to reference it, rather than duplicate it. Also, what happens when you add new data or change existing data in the `Account` table ? You'll have incorrect (not up to date) data in your `Profile` table

Comment: You can add a column to the `profiles` table, and populate it with the values from the corresponding `accounts` row with SQL. However, I agree with @Виктор , denormalizing the data should only be done after careful consideration.

Answer (score 0):

how about just using a function which access the `role` data from `accounts`

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  def role
    return account.role unless account.nil?
  end
end
```